# More training data - Less Memory

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras, ai

I have a training dataset of images common images, there are more than 5K images in this dataset. But I have less memory in Google colab- RAM-12GB.

I need to train all the images but due to less memory, I can't.

What are the possible ways to train all the images with less memory?

I have an idea, but don't know it is an optimal solution, which is

I split the dataset into 5 sets[each set contains 1000 images] and train the 1 set of dataset. Then, using the model file, I will train the 2 nd set of dataset, then again load the updated model file, I will train the 3rd set of dataset, and continues...

If I followed this steps, then it means that I trained all the images in the dataset?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. You could first try to do an ablation study with a subset of the data in order to estimate how many instances the model really needs. Maybe the performance stops increasing after 1000 images.

Comment: @Erwan, could you please share any study material for the ablation study links which you think the best, thanks

Comment: See [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/88557/64377) for instance.